# When I follow the order of operations in this equation (-2x)(4x-1)*3 I get the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this problem: (-2x)(4x-1)*3

Wouldn't the order of operations go from left to right in this? Meaning -2x times 4x which is -8x^2 and -2x times -1 which is 2x. Then were left with -8x^2+2x*3. Then we multiply 2x with 3. So the final answer would be -8x^2+2x.

When I check the answer on Google their steps are as follows: -2x(4x-1)*3 and then they multiply -2x with 3? But isn't the order of operations from left to right?

Hope my question was clear, and I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  For instance, typing `$(-2x)(4x - 1) \cdot 3$` produces $(-2x)(4x - 1) \cdot 3$, while typing `$-8x^2 + 2x$` produces $-8x^2 + 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not an order of operation in multiplications but be careful $(-2x)(4x-1)\times 3=(-8x^2+2x)\times 3=-24x^2+6x$. The general rule is, let $p_1,p_2,p_3$ be polynomials then $p_1 \times p_2\times p_3= (p_1\times p_2)\times p_3= p_1 \times (p_2 \times p_3)= p_2 \times (p_1 \times p_3)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I thought I had removed the parentheses from the binomial after multiplying it with the -2x.

Answer (score 0):

The Google result seems to be using the fact that multiplication is associative and commutative. We define the meaning of a sequence of multiplication and division from left to right, but it’s also true that $$A\cdot B\cdot C = A\cdot (B\cdot C) = A\cdot(C\cdot B) = (A\cdot C)\cdot B.$$

Perhaps whoever designed the algorithm used by Google decided it is better to multiply the simplest terms first.

You can certainly do the problem left to right. After multiplying $(-2x)$ and $(4x-1)$ you have $(-8x^2+2x).$ But then you have to multiply **all** of this by $3$. Multiplying things that are In parentheses doesn’t make the parentheses go away. The parentheses can be deleted only when they don’t make any difference in the result.

When you do $(-8x^2+2x)\times3$ you need to distribute the $3$ over both parts inside the parentheses. The result is
$-24x^2+6x.$ (This time it is OK to remove the parentheses because we no longer need them.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My mistake was not understanding that the parentheses do not disappear after multiplying the binomial with the -2x.